# how to create a dataframe based on the first appearing date and based on additional columns each id column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

i try to create a dataframe with following condition:
I have multiple IDs, multiple columns with defaults (0 or 1) and a startdate column. I would like to get a dataframe with the appearing defaults based on the first startdate (default_date) and each id.

the orginal df looks like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|id  |def_a|def_b|deb_c|date       |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|  01|    1|    0|    1| 2019-01-31|
|  02|    1|    1|    0| 2018-12-31|
|  03|    1|    1|    1| 2018-10-31|
|  01|    1|    0|    1| 2018-09-30|
|  02|    1|    1|    0| 2018-08-31|
|  03|    1|    1|    0| 2018-07-31|
|  03|    1|    1|    1| 2019-05-31|
```

this is how i would like to have it:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|id  |def_a|def_b|deb_c|date       |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|  01|    1|    0|    1| 2018-09-30|
|  02|    1|    1|    0| 2018-08-31|
|  03|    1|    1|    1| 2018-07-31|
```

i tried following code:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date".asc) 
val reult = join3.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"def_a" === 1 || $"def_b" === 1 ||$"def_c" === 1).filter($"rn" >= 1).drop("rn")
```

result.show

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Hello @Nika did you solve this one?

Comment: Hi, not yet. ist not exactly the result, that i need

Comment: Hi Nika, so what is exactly the result you need?

Comment: I thought you are looking for each group of id the record with the min date value, is not that the case?

Comment: Sorry, I had another mistake in my code. your code helped me. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome :) I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. First assign the min date to the original df then join the new df2 with df.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
(1,1,0,1,"2019-01-31"),
(2,1,1,0,"2018-12-31"),
(3,1,1,1,"2018-10-31"),
(1,1,0,1,"2018-09-30"),
(2,1,1,0,"2018-08-31"),
(3,1,1,0,"2018-07-31"),
(3,1,1,1,"2019-05-31"))
.toDF("id"  ,"def_a" , "def_b", "deb_c", "date")

val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date".asc) 

val df2 = df.withColumn("date", $"date".cast("date"))
            .withColumn("min_date", min($"date").over(w))
            .select("id", "min_date")
            .distinct()

df.join(df2, df("id") === df2("id") && df("date") === df2("min_date"))
.select(df("*"))
.show
```

And the output should be:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+
| id|def_a|def_b|deb_c|      date|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+
|  1|    1|    0|    1|2018-09-30|
|  2|    1|    1|    0|2018-08-31|
|  3|    1|    1|    0|2018-07-31|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+
```

By the way I believe you had a little mistake on your expected results. It is `(3, 1, 1, 0, 2018-07-31)` not `(3, 1, 1, 1, 2018-07-31)`